# Using a Custom Domain Name In Place of etsy

Tags: apache-2.2, url

I am thinking about creating an online shop at etsy, the one requirement I have is, I want user to see my domain name (`www.myname.com`), instead of `myname.etsy.com`.

Given that I don't have access to the etsy server, is there thing I can do on my domain redirect( assuming I am using apache), so that whatever request on `www.myname.com` will be translated to the etsy side? This is so that whoever comes to my website won't see the word etsy in the url.

Another particular thing is that I want my custom domain name to show in the web browser location bar when the redirect completes.

Is there anyway to do this with apache?

Comment: Talk to etsy support, they should be able to tell you if it's possible and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [reverse proxy mechanism](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies), *if the JS and generated links on etsy are relative or built from the request headers*.

That's a **major** if in my experience. Some of that can be fixed with the html_rewrite module (it's explained a little at my link), but that can get messy...

Going through your site will slow things down, though, and you will have to pay for the b/w. I'm not sure that what you're planning is gonna be worth it, frankly - most users IME don't care which domain it is, as long as it's fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

you could set up your apache as a reverse proxy for the shop. so apache will forward every request to the etsy system and the user will only see your domain name in his browser. for detailed configuration look at the apache documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). it has some examples and explanation of the concept.